# Determine which site a SEDE query is running on

Tags: support, data-explorer

Within a query, is there a way to determine which site the query is being run against?

For example if creating a query that has some per-site stuff built-in, like privilege thresholds, or e.g. generating URLs from IDs with the correct domain name, I'd like to be able to determine the site so I can code possibilities into the query itself.

Comment: For the second part, see the second example [in the help](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns). What type of information do you want for the first part?

Comment: @TimStone Oh sweet, `site://`! Here I thought I knew all there was to know about the magic column. For the first part I'm interested in privilege thresholds (e.g. beta vs graduated vs exceptions are different, for one query; this could alternately be solved if a privilege table was in sede) and also reputation changes (e.g. stackapps is +10 on questions not +5) and also for a recent query I made (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345978) it would've been handy to be able to do e.g. `Text LIKE current_sites_chat_server` for link testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I found a way, the [`DB_NAME()` function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/db-name-transact-sql) can be used to get the database name. Further logic can be done on the results. Example:

```
SELECT DB_NAME()
```

Results in

```
StackExchange.English
```

When run [on the English site](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/649302).

As an aside a full list of database names can be obtained with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/649303).

(Still wouldn't mind a `Privileges` table, though!)